# Cannot Connect to SQL Instance IF Server Name is from input()

Tags: python-3.x, pyodbc

I have been playing around with pyodbc and for some reason when trying to connect if I get the Server property from a input() it cannot find the server, but if I take the same server name and declare it as a variable before hand it works fine with the exact same code. Does anyone know what is going on here?

**Code with input()**

```
import pyodbc 

driver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
instance = input("Please Enter your SQL Instance: ")
connectionstring = f'Driver={driver}; Server={instance}; Trusted_Connection=yes'
conn = pyodbc.connect(connectionstring)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT name FROM sys.databases')

for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

**Output**
[Code output server name from Input()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZP4h.png)

**Code with Variable**

```
import pyodbc 

driver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
instance = 'DESKTOP-J7PBL8S\\NORTHWIND'
connectionstring = f'Driver={driver}; Server={instance}; Trusted_Connection=yes'
conn = pyodbc.connect(connectionstring)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT name FROM sys.databases')

for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

**Output**
[Code output server name from variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5c1tD.png)

I have tried using str() on the input with no luck. Not really sure why it doesn't like when I get the server name from an input because it returns a string and the connection string is exactly the same as the code that works.

I am kind of curious why this is the case not really looking to use input() on any real project

Comment: You don't need to double-up the backslash when typing the instance name at the `input` prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried:

```py
ins1 = input("Please Enter your SQL Instance: ")
ins2 = 'DESKTOP-J7PBL8S\\NORTHWIND'

print(ins1)
print(ins2)
```

Then pass the `DESKTOP-J7PBL8S\\NORTHWIND` as input and the output was:

```
DESKTOP-J7PBL8S\\NORTHWIND
DESKTOP-J7PBL8S\NORTHWIND
```

So I think we found the problem.
The `input()` returns the raw string without considering `\` special meaning.

So if you use just one `\`-> `DESKTOP-J7PBL8S\NORTHWIND`, you should be able to connect to the intended server.